# Using const std::unique_ptr for pimpl idiom

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

In [Herb Sutter's talk at CppCon16](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE) he suggested writing pimpl idiom with `const std::unique_ptr` (roughly 10 minutes in).

How is this supposed to work with move constructors/assignments? Is there something in c++17? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Without having read the talk, it's obvious that classes with pimpl are not copyable/movable. They would be instantiated in dynamic scope, and accessed exclusively via smart pointers, with pimpl hiding the internal implementation details.

Comment: Why won't you want majority of your pimpl classes to be movable? It seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @DenisYaroshevskiy can only assume he has a specific use case in mind. In general, I would agree with using `unique_ptr`as a container for pimpl. If you wanted it to be copyable, you'd have to implement that in terms of a clone operation of course.

Comment: Just watched the relevant part of the video and I disagree with him. I think for most pimpl handles, a `const unique_ptr` would become a limitation very quickly.

Comment: @RichardHodges - Sutter is right. If you copy a class with a pimpl, you either have two objects with the same pimpl, if the pimpl is a shared_ptr, or one object with no pimpl, if the pimpl is a unique_ptr. This breaks the contract of one object, one pimpl. On the other hand, an object with a `const` pimpl can still be moved.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I cannot see how a `const unique_ptr` is moveable. There is no `const unique_ptr&&` constructor. If you can provide example code I'd be intrigued. I think you'd have to write a move-constructor that moves the implementation. That still leaves one object in an undefined state. It was noteworthy that he offered no use cases of the `const unique_ptr`-as-pimpl (non)-idiom. Herb's a bright guy but he's not necessarily someone I'd follow blindly.

Answer (score 8):

If your class is supposed to be never-empty, a non-const unique ptr (with default move/assigns) is not appropriate.  The move ctor and move assign will both empty the rhs.

A const unique ptr will disable these automatic methods, and if you want move you will have to write it within the impl (and a bit of glue outside).

I would personally write a value ptr with the semantics I want (then let compiler write the glue), but starting with a const unique_ptr sounds reasonable as a first pass.

If you relax the never-empty, and make it almost never-empty, you now have to reason about preconditions of a lot of methods, and possible knock-on bugs.

The biggest cost of this technique, difficulty in returning values, goes away with C++17.

Comment: If you move out from an object it's suppose to be in partially formed state, so it can only be assigned and destructed so move constructor/assigment doesn't break your not_null guarantee. You can come up with smth like not_null from gsl to wrap it if you want to.

Comment: @DenisYaroshevskiy No, it is in whatever state you are willing to guarantee?  It isn't "supposed to be in a partially formed state" unless that is what you *choose* to guarantee.  One option is to be almost-never-empty and only be empty once moved-from.  This is a choice, it has costs and benefits.  The costs of going from never-empty to almost-never-empty should not be dismissed.  Ditto the costs of going from almost-never-empty to never-empty.  Never-empty is easier to *guarantee correctness*, and biasing towards more-often-correct code over faster code is often a good idea.

Comment: @Yakk even when a moved-from object is "never empty", using it after the move is a strong code smell. I would argue that a pimpl pointer check followed by assert/exception is preferable to allowing people to depend upon a moved-from object being in a 'default' state. This is inviting disaster when the guarantee can no longer be met due to inevitable mission creep. I would go far as to say that it is an anti-pattern that is at odds with the spirit of `std::move`.

Comment: @RichardHodges Sometimes-empty types are guaranteed disaster, as you **will** accidentally use them in a context where some possibility of them being empty.  Preventing that is *hard*.  You can fix it, but only with extensive and comprehensive QA (and if you assume perfect QA, no code is ever "dangerous").  By going with `const unique ptr`, your objects cannot be moved, and *this problem cannot occur*.  By using a specific `never_empty_ptr`, your code cannot be empty, and *this problem cannot occur*.  Hand-rolling a never-empty state into a class is, on the other hand, probably a bad idea.

Comment: @Yakk If preventing the use of moved-from objects is hard (for a given team?), then this argues for mandating a "no using `std::move`" constraint on one's (presumably substandard) developers. All the good ones will leave as soon as they can find a better job, of course, but you'll have your 'never empty' guarantee while still allowing other teams to write efficient code. I'm struggling to imagine a reasonable use case for this idiom. It undoes in one fell swoop 90% of the massive increment in utility and performance offered by trading up from c++03 to c++11.

Comment: Or just use `std::move` because *every C++ standard container behaves very reasonably post-move* (except move-assign), and every type you write can also behave reasonably post-move as well. Some objects might be "sometimes empty" (like unique ptr), but for them *all use of them needs to be guarded anyhow*. And rarely use "almost-never-empty" types, because they encourage you to assume they are never-empty while failing catastrophically when they are empty. The problem in this view is the "almost-never-empty" types, not `std::move`. Or write your move-empty types to auto-fill on *all ops*.

Answer (score 3):

> How is this suppose to work with move constructors/assignments?

[Move constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

> **The implicitly-declared or defaulted move constructor for class T is defined as deleted** if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> - T has non-static data members that cannot be moved (have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move constructors)

`const std::unique_ptr` is such a data member because of `const`.

If `const` is dropped the compiler generates the move constructor and assignment, but not the copying ones.

---

Herb explains why he uses `const unique_ptr`:

> non-const can work too, but it is more brittle because default move semantics are probably incorrect.

With `const` member it is more robust because `const` members must be initialized in the constructor. And `const` documents that the implementation of the object does not change, it is not State or Strategy design pattern.

Comment: Then in such case one would have to implement a copy constructor?

Comment: @vordhosbn If that is necessary.

Comment: That's true but my question was about move construction/assignment. Using plain unique_ptr instead of const will keep move construction/assignment alive and well while declaring it const forbids it.

I used to think that const data members is a bad practise (because of this issue) but apparently Herb Sutter doesn't think this. I wondered why.

Comment: @DenisYaroshevskiy The only reasonable answer here is that Herb did not want those special member functions to be generated to make the example simpler.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I don't believe that to be accurate, considering the context of the video.

Comment: I would argue the opposite to Mr Sutter. The default behaviour of `std::move` on `std::unique_ptr` is absolutely correct and very much what we want - an efficient transfer of state, leaving the moved-from handle in a very well defined state - "invalid, do not touch". Disabling moves explicitly is one thing (one might wonder at the motives). Disabling them through cryptic use of const just looks to me like playfulness.

Comment: @RichardHodges Yep, i would disable those special functions explicitly to avoid any doubt and to follow the principle of least surprise.

Comment: To me, the most important thing is to express lifetime by construction, and to get the defaults right (in this case, no brittle move by default). You can write the copy and move operations yourself, e.g., `MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& that) { *pimpl = *that.pimpl; return *this; }`. The `Impl` class can still be copyable and even movable, and you can delegate to it. Of course that only gets you 95% of the way, and there's no objection to also writing your own `value_ptr` type that automates the deep copy/move too.

Comment: @HerbSutter
1 - Huge thanks for coming here.
2 - So move would delegate to pimpl like other methods? Seems like I would do some work that could have been avoided if I just moved unique_ptr. Do you actually recomend doing this instead of moving unique_ptr so that we can avoid null pimpl?