# C++ - Return const unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I am wondering why I get an error when compiling:

```
const std::unique_ptr<int> get() { 
    return std::make_unique<int>(10);
}

int main() { 

    const std::unique_ptr<int> value = get();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10:44: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’
     const std::unique_ptr<int> value = get();
```

It compiles correctly when I remove `const` from the `get` signature.

Is there any way to return a constant unique_ptr ?

Comment: Is the actual `std::unique_ptr` object supposed to be constant, or the data pointed to by it?

Comment: Yes, I mean the actual `std::unique_ptr` object is supposed to be constant.

Comment: Why would you need a constant pointer to data that can be changed? That's weird.

Comment: @MooingDuck As a return type, this is weird. Otherwise, [pimpl comes to mind as a case where a const `unique_ptr` to a non-const object is sometimes used.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39703578) *In general* there's nothing weird about const pointers to non-const. If it's wrong to make the pointer point elsewhere but right to mutate the pointed-to object through the pointer, a const pointer to non-const expresses and enforces that. If one follows the somewhat common practice of making most things const except when there's a reason not to, const pointers to non-const objects arise quite often.

Comment: @EliahKagan: A `const` pointer in pimpl makes moves/swaps slower than they need to be, but yes, in general there are cases where a const pointer makes sense.

Comment: This is an x/y question that I dunno why it got voted so high. You state that you want the `unique_ptr` to be constant, despite that `const` return values are weird enough even before a noncopyable type like `unique_ptr` is added into the mix, without explaining why you thought you wanted this oddity. I don't feel that 'why can I not do [weird thing without any apparent justification]' questions are useful, otherwise I could spend my whole day inventing and posting them.

Comment: @MooingDuck There seem to be plenty of cases where `const` pointers are a good idea, at least if one values `const`-correctness. Sure, if we have full control over the function signature, a reference should be used. However, a trivial example that comes to mind where a pointer is received is a stdlib algorithm like `find_if` over a range in a container holding pointers (`reference_wrapper` doesn't seem worth the hassle & should be `const` itself anyway!). If the possibility were left of accidentally mutating the pointer within the receiving function, & that happens, it's not going to end well.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Because the `unique_ptr` is constant it can not be moved only copied. And copying a `unique_ptr` is not allowed (otherwise it would not be "unique").

If the data pointed to by the pointer should be constant, then use `std::unique_ptr<const int>` instead.

Comment: Just a quick note: OP's example has to compile in C++17 due to guaranteed copy elision.

Comment: @bogdan Are you sure? It doesn't compile for me on clang, gcc, or msvc with `-std=c++17`

Comment: @bogdan The `std::unique_ptr` copy-constructor and copy-assignment operators are marked as `delete`, which means it can't be used for any kind of copying, even if the copy can be elided.

Comment: @patatahooligan Could those be older versions of the compilers? It does compile for me using reasonably recent versions of all three, Clang 5, GCC 7.3, MSVC 15.9.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's true and applies in this case for anything before C++17. The rules have changed in C++17 as a result of adopting [P0135](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html). Rationale and examples are in the [R0 version of the paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html). Basically, initializing from a prvalue of the same type as the destination is no longer seen as a copy/move from a temporary that can be elided; it explicitly creates the destination object based on the prvalue; there isn't anything to elide anymore.

Comment: @bogdan My mistake. I did a bunch of tests and got the results mixed up. OP's example does compile as you stated. The one that doesn't compile is returning a local const unique_ptr. Even though this should be elided in practice, the class is still required to be copyable.