# Making a constant unique_ptr to a const vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, unique-ptr

I want to create a vector of integers. Once created I want to shuffle the
integers in order to have a random order of integers. This will be used for testing the sorting functions.

Now, no sorting algorithm will be allowed to sort the vector in-place and hence we need to make the vector a constant. Also - I do not want anyone to be able to change the `unique_ptr` and point it to something else.

Q1. How do we achieve it.

Current Solution:

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279783/c-return-const-unique-ptr) and [this](http://www.codingstandard.com/rule/8-2-4-do-not-pass-stdunique_ptr-by-const-reference/) and other references, I have done the following.

I am creating a vector, assign it to unique pointer to make sure that it is guarded against memory leaks and gets automatically deleted when we go out of scope.  We shuffle the vector and then move this vector to a new one which has type as (`const std::vector<int>`). We then move the pointer to a const unique pointer.

In the code below I have coded the current solution. Let me know if there is a better way of doing it.

I am using c++17 for compiling the program.

```
#include <random>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::unique_ptr<const std::vector <int>>
createConstVector(int numberOfElements, int increments) {
    auto v = std::make_unique <std::vector<int>> (numberOfElements);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::generate(v->begin(), v->end(),
                  [n=0, increments] () mutable { n = n + increments; return n;});
    std::shuffle(v->begin(), v->end(), g);
    std::unique_ptr<const std::vector<int>> v2 = std::move(v);
    return std::move(v2);
}

auto sortUsingStdSort(std::unique_ptr<const std::vector<int>> const &vectorToSort) {
  auto v = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>> (*vectorToSort);

  std::sort(v->begin(), v->end());
  return std::move(v);
}

int main () {
  const std::unique_ptr<const std::vector <int>> u3 = createConstVector(10, 5);
  auto sortedVector = sortUsingStdSort(u3);
  for(auto v : *sortedVector) {
    std::cout << " " << v;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `const vector<int>` instead of `std::unique_ptr<const std::vector <int>>` ?

Comment: I think you're overthinking things. I see no need for `unique_ptr` whatsoever.

Comment: I am unwilling to use raw pointers unless there is no way out of using them. Hence I am using unique_ptr.

Comment: We said: `auto sortUsingStdSort(const std::vector<int>& vectorToSort) {
  std::vector<int> v = vectorToSort;
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
  return v;
}`               `

Comment: The second [link](http://www.codingstandard.com/rule/8-2-4-do-not-pass-stdunique_ptr-by-const-reference/) seems wrong to me. `std::unique_ptr` is `non copyable`. You cannot pass it by value, while `reference`, `move` and `const reference` are fine.

Comment: @RishiAgrawal Nobody's suggesting that you use raw pointers. The suggestion is to not use any kind of pointer.

Comment: @SaileshD I'm pretty sure the point of the rule in that second link is that anywhere you would accept a `const unique_ptr<T>&` you're better off just accepting a `T*` (or `T&`) since there is no transfer of ownership either way and the latter is more flexible.

Comment: @RishiAgrawal that is a completely arbitrary limitation that will prevent you from writing any kind of moderately complex code idiomatically. A raw pointer and a `std::unique_ptr` have completely different roles.

Comment: @SaileshD: `void foo (std::unique_ptr p_sink);` is fine, just call `foo(std::move(existing_unique_ptr))` or `foo(std::move(std::make_unique<T>(..)))`.

Comment: @SaileshD you can initialize value function parameters by moving an object into them. That's why they're described as sinks.

Comment: @RishiAgrawal: *"`void foo (std::unique_ptr const & p_impl_detail); // @@- Non-Compliant -@@`"*, and you do it for `sortUsingStdSort`...

Comment: If your code works, take it to Code Review. SO is for solving problems.

Comment: @Jarod42 - you want to completely remove the use of unique_ptr. I understand that this will make the program simple. But that again - will result in either using raw pointers or allocating vector on the stack. As far as I understand, using raw pointers is discouraged. Let me know if I am incorrect. I am quite new to modern cpp - so please ignore my stupidity.

Comment: @RishiAgrawal Yes, just make the vector an automatic variable.  A vector is already basically just a unique_ptr to its managed array (with some extra methods for doing vectory stuff).  There's no reason to dynamically allocate the vector itself in this case.

Comment: @RishiAgrawal No worries, ignorance is not the same as stupidity! Everyone needs to start somewhere. Often, using values directly is easier and safer. Other times, passing by reference is the best solution, like here.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I was unaware of this. But now I understand - the pointer will be allocated on the stack, but the "pushed" elements will be made using the heap. I guess this will be same for all the containers.

Comment: [simplified code](https://ideone.com/KVoIZN) (I also move generator to seed only once in main).

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks a lot. This helped me a lot in understanding the "const" and unique_ptr related concepts.

Comment: @Jarod42 As far as I understand we have removed the unique pointers from the code because there is no `ownership` involved. Also the second use of unique_ptr is wrt to memory leaks - which again got handled by the way Vectors are implemented. 

The above code was a part of an self-practice assignment where I was trying to use the unique_ptr to understand more about it.

I need some more guidance over here. It will be a great help if you can suggest a small problem which I can solve in a day or two and which requires the use of unique_ptr in some way.

Comment: @RishiAgrawal: you might use `unique_ptr` in list implementation. or with collection of polymorphism classes (`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you would write it without raw pointers, without unnecessary `unique_ptr` usage, and without `std::move`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>
createVector(int numberOfElements, int increments) {
    auto v = std::vector<int>(numberOfElements);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(),
                  [n=0, increments] () mutable { n = n + increments; return n;});
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
    return v;
}

auto sortUsingStdSort(std::vector<int> v) {
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
  return v;
}

int main() {
  const std::vector<int> u3 = createVector(10, 5);
  auto sortedVector = sortUsingStdSort(u3);
  for(auto v : sortedVector) {
    std::cout << " " << v;
  }
}
```

The vector is passed by `const` reference, so no unnecessary copying there. Vectors are returned by value, but we can rely on [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) to avoid copying here too.

The only place where a copy is made is for the argument to the `sortUsingStdSort` function, where we are explicitly requesting it.

Comment: thanks a lot. This enabled me to understand the whole "const"  and unique_ptr thing in a different way.

Comment: `const` is, in my opinion, one of the best features of C++. Understand it well, and you cannot help starting to love it.

Comment: `sortUsingStdSort` may as well accept by value, and not copy in the body. Then you avoid copying from an r-value argument

Comment: In ```createVector``` I would make ```rd``` and ```g``` ```static```.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I didn't want to change more than needed to answer the question. This isn't codereview.stackexchange.com.